# ASP NET The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos no sé que pasó o que hice, pero derrepente me empezó a salir este error a la hora de hacer login en **ASP** con **EF**

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No cambie nada en mi bd , alguien sabe a que se debe?

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Modelo LoginViewModel

```
  public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Indica por favor el código.

Comment: voy a subirlo pero es el código que me trae EF

Comment: Tienes el código del Modelo `LoginViewModel` ?

Comment: ya lo subo @RafaelAcosta

Comment: Tu problema es bastante común con EF y ASP.NET Identity por lo que he visto en Inet. Mírate esto : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201321/applicationsigninmanager-class-throws-invalid-cast-exception. Yo sigo buscando información.